# Best way to travel from Palenque to Mexico city by road

Tags: budget, buses, mexico

I need you guys help with this.

I am planning to travel some parts of Mexico from Jan 2 - 7th. Palenque or Villahermosa would be my last destination and from there, I need to get to Mexico City in the morning or early afternoon on Jan 7th at the latest.

Please give me some advice on this trip. I need the cheapest way to get back to the city. I am a college student so I could get a discount on bus ticket right? When I searched it, it seems to be that ADO bus company is only option. Am I right on this? Help me out guys!!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By road yes, that is the only option I´m aware of, but be aware it is a 12 hour trip by road. If your budget allows it I´d definetly consider taking a flight. Volaris is a low cost carrier that offers flights from Villahermosa to Mexico City